# Вывод страны один раз в php

Tags: php, sql

```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT country.country_ru AS country__country_ru,
                   city.city_ru       AS city__city_ru
     FROM tour
LEFT JOIN city 
       ON tour.city = city.id
LEFT JOIN country 
       ON city.country = country.id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так вот как выводит на php чтобы один раз повтарялся страна и города в были группы страны

```
<select>

 <optgroup label="Азербайджан">
  <option>Баку</option>
  <option>Шуша</option>
 </optgroup>

 <optgroup label="Турция">
  <option>Анталья</option>
 </optgroup>

</select>
```

Comment: в PDO есть встроенная группировка по полю. а так сортируйте по стране, а когда цикле записи выводите смотрите сменилась страна или нет, если сменилась, то добавляете к выводу `</optgroup><optgroup ... >`

Comment: а можно примерный код?

Answer (score 0):

```php
$arr = [
    [
        'country__country_ru' => 'Азербайджан',
        'city__city_ru' => 'Баку',
    ],
    [
        'country__country_ru' => 'Турция',
        'city__city_ru' => 'Анталья',
    ],
    [
        'country__country_ru' => 'Азербайджан',
        'city__city_ru' => 'Шуша',
    ],
];

$prep = [];

foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    if (! isset($prep[ $row['country__country_ru'] ])) {
        $prep[ $row['country__country_ru'] ] = [];
    }

    $prep[ $row['country__country_ru'] ] []= $row['city__city_ru'];
}

$html = "<select>\n";

foreach ($prep as $country => $cities)
{
    $html .= "  <optgroup label=\"$country\">\n";

    foreach ($cities as $city)
    {
        $html .= "    <option>$city</option>\n";
    }

    $html .= "  </optgroup>\n";
}

$html .= "</select>\n";

echo $html;
```